# Do long running transactions bog down databases?

Tags: django, postgresql, transactions

Note: I'm using Postgres 9.x and Django ORM

I have some functions in my application which open a transaction, run a few queries, then do a couple full seconds of other things (3rd party API access, etc.), and then run a few more queries. The queries aren't very expensive,, but I've been concerned that, by having many transactions open for so long, I'll somehow bog down my database eventually or run out of connections or something. How big of a deal is this, performance-wise?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keeping a transaction open has pros and cons.

On the plus side, every transaction has an overhead cost. If you can do a couple of related things in one transaction, you normally win performance.

However, you acquire locks on rows or whole tables along the way (especially with any kind of write operation). These are automatically released at the end of the transaction. If other processes might wait for the same resources, it is a **very bad idea** to call external processes while the transaction stays open.

Maybe you can do the call to the 3rd party API *before* you acquire any locks, and do all queries in swift succession afterwards?

Read about [checking locks in the Postgres Wiki](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Lock_Monitoring).

Comment: Would the suggestion at the end suffice (swift succession), even if the transaction was open the whole time? (e.g., open transaction, do a few read-only queries, do time consuming processing via 3rd party API, do all queries, commit)

Comment: @orokusaki: The problematic case would be to acquire locks and keep them open for a long time. As long as you don't acquire any locks before the external call, it shouldn't stall anything - except of course lower level tasks like restarting the server gracefully. SELECT should be fine. I added a link to my answer.

Comment: Agreed that there are pros and cons. The scale of time matters a lot; a few seconds usually is no big deal if you're not holding explicit table locks. Once you get past a few minutes you may start to interfere with normal maintenance activities to some extent or other. If it gets to hours or days, you're likely to suffer performance-sapping bloat in your tables if there is much other activity going on.*

Comment: Thanks guys - the duration of wait in my app will be measured in seconds (10 max, but usually around 1.5). I'm not using any table locks, but I am locking a single row of one table (using `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`). There are cases where 2 or more threads will be trying to select the same row, but it will be extremely rare (not non-existent though, hence `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` in the first place). So, all these transactions open for a while aren't that expensive, so long as the resources they're locking aren't in high-demand, sound right? I was worried about connection overhead or something.

Answer (score 2):

While not exact answer, I can't recommend this presentation highly enough.

[“PostgreSQL When It’s Not Your Job” at DjangoCon US](http://thebuild.com/presentations/not-my-job-djangocon-us.pdf)

It is from this year's DjangoCon, so there should be a video also, hopefully soon.

Plus check out authors blog, it's a golden mine of useful information on Postgres as a whole and django in particular. You'll find interesting info about transaction handling there.

Comment: Thanks, that was a helpful talk (slides).

Comment: There is a new updated version here: http://thebuild.com/blog/2017/03/29/postgresql-when-its-not-your-job/